# javascript onload play audio file

Tags: javascript, html

I have an audio file with a button when I click on it the audio play and when I click again the audio pause I also want when the page is load the audio play directly without clicking on the button

- I tried `autoplay` in the html but it didn't work
- I tried `allow="autoplay"`  also it didn't work
- I tried `window.addEventListener('load')` also it didn't work

I read that I should use `muted` but also it didn't work

I'm using chrome and firefox

How can I make this audio work on refresh or on load for the page and when i click in the button the audio will be pause it and when I click again the audio will be played

I searched on stack overflow but nothing solve my problem

```js
let audio = document.querySelector('.music audio');
let audioBtn = document.querySelector('.music .musicBtn i');

audio.volume = 0.2;

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  audio.play();
  
});

audioBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (audio.paused) {
    audio.play();
    audioBtn.classList.add('fa-volume-up');
    audioBtn.classList.remove('fa-volume-mute');
  } else {
    audio.pause();
    audioBtn.classList.add('fa-volume-mute');
    audioBtn.classList.remove('fa-volume-up');

  }
});
```

```css
.musicBtn {
    background: transparent;
    padding: 1.5rem 2rem;
    font-size: 3rem;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="music">
  <audio id="audio" style="display:none;" src="music/music.mp3" allow="autoplay" controls autoplay loop></audio>
  <button class="musicBtn"><i class="fas "></i></button>
</div>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9e5ba2e3f5.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: The user needs to interact with a page before audio or video will play.  This is a measure browsers have put in place to prevent non-consensual audio.  Are you accounting for this?

Comment: have you tried the `oncanplay` event? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oncanplay.asp

Comment: @schwaber oncanplay it doesn't work also

Answer (score 0):

You can not, as browsers only allow playing sounds as a consequence of user-interaction. You could try to hijack any click or mouse movement to enable the plaining of sound, but there is no way to really do it on load alone.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide

Answer (score 0):

You can try manual interaction by clicking on the play button on DOM load so that the audio plays,

```
if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
   document.getElementById('#playButton').click();
}
```